# How do I ignore folders and its subdirectories in Unison sync

Tags: linux, sync, unison

I use [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to sync website projects across my machines, in one of my machines I would like to avoid sycning (both ways)some folders contained with in the folders I watch:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
/storage/debugbar
/staroge/framework
```

This is the profile I use to .prf file I use to execute the sync, you can see that the folders are there in the ignore path lines.

```
# Roots of the synchronization
root = /Volumes/Data HD
root = ssh://Server//volume1/My Files

# Paths
path = Sites

# Some regexps specifying names and paths to ignore
ignore = Name */@eaDir
ignore = Name */_notes
ignore = Name .DS_Store
ignore = Name SyncToy_*.dat
ignore = Path */Archives
ignore = Path */tools
ignore = Name *.sublime*

# Ignore laravel composer and npm folders
ignore = Path {Sites/CRMJobs/node_modules}
ignore = Path {Sites/Loot/node_modules}
ignore = Path {Sites/Pompous/node_modules}
ignore = Path */vendor
ignore = Path */node_modules
ignore = Path */storage/debugbar
ignore = Path */storage/framework

log = true
times = true
auto = true
```

You can see that in some cases I've even explicitly mentioned full patches to ignore yet they are still synchronised.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The only thing I could think of right now is: what is the topology you are using to synchronize across multiple machines? I am asking because only the `.prf` file on the machine initiating the connection is taken into account. Could it be the case that you're initiating the sync from a machine that doesn't have the correct `.prf` file? By the way, you may want to consider synchronizing those `.prf` files, too!

Comment: But why did you cross-post to SU and SO at the same time?

Comment: I posted on both in an effort to get an answer quickly, will remove the SO version. I am using the star topology to sync. I don't think having the same .prf file is the issue as the central machine usually receives all data under my `Sites` directory but depending on which machine I'm using I'll only sync certain subdirectories.

Comment: could it be that the machine where you execute `unison` from doesn't have a `.prf` file with the `ignore` lines?

Comment: `ignore = Name .DS_Store` works here. Could it be that the directive is overrridden by some other directive? Have you tried to isolate it to only this directive?

Answer (score 12):

See this [bit on Path Specification](https://ftp.tw.freebsd.org/distfiles/unison-2.48.3/unison-2.48.3-manual.html#pathspec) in the Unison manual. Instead of `Path` you should use `Name`.

```
ignore = Name vendor
ignore = Name node_modules
ignore = Name storage/debugbar
ignore = Name storage/framework
```

Answer (score 1):

I used one big ignore regex to do this because all other approaches didn't work. If unison would support negative lookaheads, this would have been so much simple, but I had to use an emulation through negative character classes as described here:

https://clusterise.com/articles/regex-negative-lookahead/

If I want only 2 subfolders e.g. "abc" and "def" to be included, I use something like the following:

`Regex ^([^ad].*|a[^b].*|ab[^c].*|d[^e].*|de[^f].*)`

which kind emulates the negative lookahead `^(?!abc|def)`